# openshift + spring websocket

Tags: spring, websocket, openshift, spring-websocket

I'm new to openshift and currently trying to set up my websocket application there, but have some issues. While I'm trying to connect to

*ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000/path*

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.Server Container' ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that
supports JSR-356?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.getContainer(TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.getSupportedExtensions(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler.doHandshake(DefaultHandshakeHandler.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:127)
    ... 25 more
```

When I run application locally everything works fine with the following url:

*ws://localhost:8090/path*

For both cases I use Tomcat 7. 
Spring Config:

```
<websocket:handlers allowed-origins="*">
    <websocket:mapping path="/fight-core" handler="webSocketHandler"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <ref bean="webSocketHandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>
```

Also I've tried with websocket-api dependency in my pom.xml and w/o it

Kidnly advice

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's not about Spring nor Tomcat, but Openshift's routing layer; it looks like websocket support is still experimental, see:
* [a blog post from 2012 explaining the situation](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/)
* [Openshift official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Binding_Applications_to_Ports.html)

> For plain WebSocket connections (ws://), requests are directed to port
>   8000, while WebSocket Secure connections (wss://) use port 8443, as
>   shown in the following example: http://example.example.com:8000
>   https://example.example.com:8443